# Mailgun track unique opens

Tags: php, yii2, mailgun

Just tested mailgun through its API.

Everything is working fine.

**Short: How to track unique opens for a specific mail through webhooks.**

---

(Not necessarily relevant but for completness I use Yii2 PHP framework - no extension, just the quick start php code from mailgun)

The emails get sent and it tracks the open event.
But I discovered that it tracks every single open of the same mail.

So what is the best way to track if a specific mail is opened (through webhook). Which data is best for identifiing the specific email or better use “custom variables” when sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I think I got an acceptable workflow - through the “custom variables”.

You can define different values for each recipient, so you can send a unique id and then track that id on the open events. And just save one open for each sender or update the open time.

My sending code (PHP):

```
$result = $mg->sendMessage($domain, array(
            'from'    => 'foo@bar.de>',
            'to'      => 'recipient1@mail.de, recipient2@mail.de',
            'subject' => 'Hello %recipient.first% from %recipient.group%!',
            'text'    => 'Test of Mailgun',
            'html'    => '<html>It is so simple to send a message.<br/>Right?</html>',
            'o:tag'   => array('test'),
            'o:tracking-opens' => 'yes',
            'v:my-custom-data' => '{"my_message_id": %recipient.id%}',
            'recipient-variables' => '{
                "recipient1@mail.de": {"first":"Recipient1", "group":"group1", "id":1},
                "recipient2@mail.de": {"first":"Recipient2", "group":"group2", "id":2}
            }'
));
```

Then in each event you get a response with the unique ids.

Open event of first email:

```
"user-variables": {
    "my-custom-data": "{\"my_message_id\": 1}"
},
```

Open event of second email:

```
"user-variables": {
    "my-custom-data": "{\"my_message_id\": 2}"
},
```

Comment: Hi michaK, if you could share your thoughts about Mailgun click tracking at https://stackoverflow.com/q/53993044/470749, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to track email openings is so called "pixel". 
First you need to inject pixel in your email.

For example:

```
    public function insertPixel($user,$template)
        {
            $output = $template.'<img src="'.Yii::app()->homeUrl.'/mailing/pixel/track?id='.$this->campaign->id.'&user='.$user.'&rand='.rand().'">';

            return $output;
        }
```

Which points to php endpoint. At that endpoint you will get openings and do w/e you want with them.

For example:

```
public function actionTrack()
{
    if (isset($_GET["id"])&&isset($_GET["user"])){
            Yii::app()->db->createCommand("UPDATE mailing_campaigns SET open_count = open_count + 1 WHERE id=:id")
                ->bindParam(":id",$_GET["id"],PDO::PARAM_INT)
                ->execute();
    }
    header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    echo "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x37\x61\x1\x0\x1\x0\x80\x0\x0\xfc\x6a\x6c\x0\x0\x0\x2c\x0\x0\x0\x0\x1\x0\x1\x0\x0\x2\x2\x44\x1\x0\x3b";
    exit;
}
```

This code adjusts open's counter for mailing campaign for example and returns 1x1 transparent `.gif` image.

It's not 100% precise because some people not loading images in emails, but its best way I know so far.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my question was how to do this in mailgun (mailgun.com). Mailgun handles the tracking pixel itself so my question is more about the right params or Workflow

Comment: https://documentation.mailgun.com/quickstart-events.html#events opened event. Bind to webhook to your endpoint. As far as i understood in few minutes :)

Comment: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#tracking-opens more precise. But i gave basics of tracking (maybe sometime you'll want/need to create mailing module).